# Typoscript: how do I change a select statement when a record exists

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-10.x

I want to detect if a frontend user submits a form (with saved in the db) then hide the uid 883, but for the DB statement it only grab data with an given uid, i have only the user_id or the user_name so it must search over the database.
My current TypoScript try:

```
page.10.variables.CONTENT < styles.content.get
page.10.variables.CONTENT.select.where = colPos=0 AND uid!=883
page.10.variables.CONTENT.select.where.if{
    value = 0
    equals.data = DB:tt_content:???:??
    negate = 1
}
```

anyone have a idea to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know what you want to achieve and how the data is exactly structured but I suggest to use a `USER` cObject to fetch e.g. tHE correct id.

In PHP you got much better control instead of TypoScript. An example can look like this
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/UserAndUserInt/Index.html#example-1